# HMTL comment on SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, html, web

I'm editing a usual sharepoint page programatically. I'm setting a page content like this :

```
"<!--startSub-->" Hello this is a content. "<!--endSub-->"
```

and edited the page.
So comments helps me to find a part of text to replace it next time when I edit my page. But when I read a Sharepoint page content I'm getting my content without my comments, like this:

```
Hello this is a content.
```

So I should get my comments also to replace a part of the content and edit it again.

So can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to to change the "<" character to

`&lt;`

and the ">" character to

```
&gt;
```

since the "<", ">", and "&" are escaped HTML Entities.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it is showing in SharePoint page. I want my `<!--startSub-->` as a comment in html not in SharePoint page

Comment: Hmm.. It looks like I failed to understand your question..